# My browser sends fetch data request continuously and it gives pending status after giving 200 several times in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying post some data in mongodb database and it works perfectly until the fetch request is sending continuously even if I didn't do anything. In the network tab, it shows 200 status firstly but then pending and gives error.

```
 const [services, setServices] = useState([]);
  const [treatment, setTreatment] = useState(null);

  fetch('http://localhost:5000/services')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setServices(data));
```

The error is giving after adding the following code:

```
const booking = {
      treatmentId: _id,
      treatment: name,
      date: formattedDate,
      slot,
      patientEmail: user.email,
      patient: user.displayName,
      phone: e.target.mobile.value
    }

    fetch('http://localhost:5000/booking', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(booking)
    }).then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data, 'success');
        toast('Appointment has been set!!!');
      })
```

The following error occurs:

```
bundle.js:701          GET http://localhost:5000/services net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
AppointmentSchedules @ bundle.js:701
renderWithHooks @ bundle.js:53492
updateFunctionComponent @ bundle.js:57611
beginWork @ bundle.js:59578
beginWork$1 @ bundle.js:64465
performUnitOfWork @ bundle.js:63626
workLoopSync @ bundle.js:63539
renderRootSync @ bundle.js:63508
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ bundle.js:62805
workLoop @ bundle.js:75228
flushWork @ bundle.js:75202
performWorkUntilDeadline @ bundle.js:75486
bundle.js:701          Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at AppointmentSchedules (bundle.js:701:3)
    at renderWithHooks (bundle.js:53492:22)
    at updateFunctionComponent (bundle.js:57611:28)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:59578:20)
    at beginWork$1 (bundle.js:64465:18)
    at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:63626:16)
    at workLoopSync (bundle.js:63539:9)
    at renderRootSync (bundle.js:63508:11)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (bundle.js:62805:78)
    at workLoop (bundle.js:75228:38)
```

Note: The server side is okay and working without any error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When fetching apis in react, you should use useEffect or useLayoutEffect. See
[useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) or [useLayoutEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect)

Answer (score 1):

useEffect with no dependency only run on first render

```js
const [services, setServices] = useState([]);
const [treatment, setTreatment] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/services')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setServices(data));
}, [])
```